# How to install opencv contribution to python

Tags: python, opencv, pycharm, anaconda, conda

I want to install Opencv with contributions to my python. I am using PyCharm with conda Environment 3.6. I want to use the opencv contribution package from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#openpiv

But I only get "...not a supported wheel on this platform"

I tried it with pip in the terminal, also in the command promt

I tried it with conda Environment and the normal way (python 3.7.1)

I uninstalled opencv and updated  pip. I tried different Version (cp36, cp37, 32 and 64-bit, 3.4.5 and also 4.0.1

I dont know anymore to do. Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Have you tried `conda install opencv` in the terminal?

Comment: yes. this works, but i want the contribution package, so it doesnt help :/

Comment: Try: `pip install opencv-contrib-python`. Use this command once you have uninstalled opencv. (https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/) For Windows only, one can use `conda install -c michael_wild opencv-contrib ` but it may not be the most recent version of it.